# Reftex cross-reference files in different directories

Tags: emacs, auctex, reftex

My latex files are stored in a directory structure as this

```
- main.tex
- .dir-locals.el
-- sections/
--- sec1.tex, sec2.tex, ...
-- tables/
--- table1.tex, table2.tex, ...
```

In **main.tex**, **sec1.tex** is *"imported"* as `\input{sections/sec1}`; In **sec1.tex**, table1.tex is *"imported"* as `\input{tables/table1.tex}`. I have already specify `TeX-master` as `"main.tex"` in **.dir-locals.el** like this:

```
((latex-mode
 (TeX-master . "main.tex")))
```

All **.tex** files under the root directory knows the correct master file. But my problem is that reftex cannot detect labels in **table1.tex** when I am editing **sec1.tex** (It works correctly when I edit **main.tex**). The reason seems to be that when I am in **sec1.tex** the code `\input{tables/table1.tex}` would let reftex to think there is a **"tables"** directory inside the **"sections"** directory.

My particular problem is different from [How to use reftex in multiple files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195002/how-to-use-reftex-in-multiple-files)
and
[RefTex Multiple files problems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124501/reftex-multiple-files-problems)
, because the nested modular input structure is relative only to the master file, but not so from the perspective of a slave file.

### Can anyone help me with this please? How can I let reftex to reference labels from **table1.tex** when I edit **sec1.tex**?

Update: here is an example.

**.dir-locals.el**:

```
((latex-mode
  (TeX-master ."main.tex")))
```

**main.tex**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is main.tex. \\
\input{sections/sec1}
This is main.tex referencing Section~\ref{sec:foo}.
This is main.tex referencing Table~\ref{tab:foobar}.\\
main.tex ends here.
\end{document}
```

**sections/sec1.tex**:

```
\section{foo} \label{sec:foo}
This is from sec1.tex. \\
\input{tables/table1}
This is sec1.tex referencing Table~\ref{tab:foobar}. \\
sec1.tex ends here.
```

**tables/table1.tex**:

```
\begin{table}[h]
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    A & B \\
    1 & 2
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{foobar}
  \label{tab:foobar}
\end{table}
```

In reftex, the command `reftex-reference` (press `C-c )`) would provide labels when I edit **main.tex**, as expected. But the problem is that it would not detect label `tab:foobar` when I edit **sec1.tex**.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What I have to offer is not a real solution, but a trick: What about adding a link from `sections/tables` to `../tables`? Under Linux/Unix/MacOS, you would issue the command `ln -s ../tables` in the `sections` directory; under Windows it has to be done differently, but should also be possible.

Comment: @gernot what you suggest would be difficult for a git repository though.

Comment: The problem would go away if you simply didn't use all the sub-directories. Unlike in other contexts, in the world of complex *TeX documents, 'tidying' things up by creating a sub-directory for every little thing only serves to complicate things. No one is going to confuse `sec1.tex` with `table2.tex`, after all.... If anything, use `-output-directory` to place the output in a different location.

Comment: Adding links, as @jon suggests, would not worry a git repository at all: you simply don't track these files! (Git only tracks the files that you explicitly tell it to.) I haven't used `reftex`, and you have not provided a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228), (so it isn't straightforward for me to test this) but I suspect that setting the environment variable `TEXINPUTS` to search the subdirectories may solve your problem.

Comment: Andrew offers a hint for a solution, but note that you would not be able to use `\input` the way you are now using it. (This is a good thing, in fact, because you are sort of mis-using it as it stands.)

Comment: @jon Could you elaborate on why using sub-directories would cause problems, what other issues could it cause? I know flattening the directories would solve my specific problem in reftex, but I am not aware of other problems yet.

Comment: There are no other real problems (as far as I know). I didn't say problems, I just said using sub-directories complicates things and confers very little benefit. Keeping all `.tex` files in the same location is the expectation of `TEXINPUTS` as the hack `\input{path/to/texfile.tex}` indicates. Thus, have a generally directory for the `.tex` and `.sty` files, and use `-output-directory` or a `Makefile` to control where the resulting PDF shows up. The alternative is to (locally) fiddle with TEXINPUTS, which is an acceptable option; but then you would need to use `\input` as it is intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution. The cause of the problem is `TeX-master` is not specified correctly.

`TeX-master` should be set as the plain absolute path like `"path/to/main.tex"`, or in the case of a git repository, should be programmatically set to a correct absolute path.

When edit any .tex file `reftex` can now retrieve labels specified elsewhere as long as they are "imported" to the master file, along with a correct toc tree.